# How to use awk counting the number of specificed digit in certain column

Tags: bash, csv, gawk, awk

How can I count the matched value in the certain column?

I have a file:(wm.csv)

I executed the command to get the targeted value in certain column: `tail -n +497 wm.csv | awk -F"," '$2=="2" {print $3" "$4}'`

then I get the following output data I want:

`hit 2
hit 2
hit 2
hit 2
miss 
hit 2
hit 2
hit 2
hit 2
hit 2
hit 2
hit 2
incorrect 1
hit 2
hit 2
hit 2`

I want to count the number of "2" in second column in order to do simple math like: total digits in column divided by total number of row. Specifically, in this case, it would looks like: **14** (fourteen "2" in second column) **/** **16**(total number of row)

Following is the command I tried but this does not work :
`tail -n +497 wm.csv | awk -F"," '$2=="2" {count=0;} { if ($4 == "2") count+=1 } {print $3,$4,$count }'`

thanks

Comment: show how it should print the final result including total calculations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

taking the posted data as input file

```
$ awk '$2==2{c++} END{print NR,c,c/NR}' file

16 14 0.875
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk  '($0 ~ "hit 2"){count += 1}  END{print count, FNR, count/FNR}' sample.csv
14 16 0.875
```

I use `~` to compare the whole line($0) matches "hit 2", if it is increase counter by 1. `FNR` is the file number of records which is the total line number.

Comment: This would match for example `non-hit 22`.

Comment: @JamesBrown you're right. it depends on the real lines, my post is only for the sample OP posted.  If that's the case `awk -F, '($2=="2")'...`